# Ulimit not respected in GNU bash OSX

Tags: bash, osx, gnu

I am seeing a strange issue with gnu bash in OSX. The value of ulimit -f is being changed by the bash itself. Small reproducible code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

ulimit -f 1
echo "Value: $(ulimit -f)"

echo "---"

outstring=$(echo {1..10000})
echo "Value: $(ulimit -f)"
echo "Size = ${#outstring}"
echo "$outstring" > output_file

Output:
Value: 1
---
Value: unlimited
Size = 48893

wc -c output_file 
48894 output_file
```

Version of bash

```
/usr/local/bin/bash --version | head -n1
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0)
```

Observations: The same code works as expected in ubuntu and file is not written. However, under OSX, I see this strange issue where ulimit is getting changed underneath me. Is there something I am missing or is it a bug?

Comment: I see similar behavior; something seems to be updating the ulimit value pretty frequently:  `ulimit -f 1; ulimit -f; ulimit -f; sleep 1; ulimit -f` gives me `1 1 unlimited`

Comment: It seems to change whenever there's a `fork()`.  If you remove all the `$(...)` in the code then the `ulimit` value is left untouched.  But as soon as you call an external command (eg `sleep`) then the value is reset.

Comment: Yes I noticed that and wanted to know why this is happening only on OSX.